# How to copy a view in odoo 10.0

Tags: python, odoo

my knowledge about python is very small. but I need it for the class to copy the view of this module https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/fleet_car_workshop/, exactly the worksheet_views.xml.

I need to have orginal views and copy view in one menu - I can do it. But one view must remain unchanged, and the other would like to change content and appearance.

The problem is this - when I edit a copy, the original view also changes.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you want to do? If you want the original to not do changes if you change the copied xml, try not to inherit or copy it. Make a new one

Comment: Look into inhertiance in odoo whatever you want change use inheritance otherwise leave the same